# Can You Explain This Void Pointer Inside Function Paramter?

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree, void

Here is the code in question! I have not spent too much time with C++, and I'm implementing a Binary Search Tree.

```
void BST::Preorder(void(*visit)(const Node *))
```

Later on the function is called like this:

```
bst.Preorder(PrintNode)
```

With PrintNode being implemented as follows:

```
void PrintNode(const Node* n)
{
    cout << n->GetValue() << ",";
}
```

Asked to implement this Preorder function-- but I am very confused as to what's going on here. Can anyone please point me in the proper direction. Thank you.

Comment: [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/?q=void%28*visit%29%28const+class+Node+*%29%3B) says that `void(*visit)(const Node *);` means "declare `visit` as pointer to function (pointer to const class Node) returning void".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `Preorder` is a function that will iterate through all the nodes in the binary search tree (in a particular order) and do **something** at each node. So it's useful to write `Preorder` in such a way that the caller of `Preorder` can specify what is to be done at each node. That is the purpose of the `visit` parameter. It's a function (actually a function pointer) that `Preorder` should call at every node it visits. In the example you've been given each node is going to be printed, but by supplying a different function as the parameter to `Preorder` you could make it do something different.

Comment: Thank you. This way I can call ```Visit(current node)``` each time it will hit a new node, causing the ```PrintNode``` function to execute. However, how can I do this recursively? Let me know if I can clarify. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's correct. It's your `Preorder` function that is supposed to be recursive. Since that's the main point of the exercise I think I should leave you to figure that out. You can always google 'preorder binary tree traversal' and I'm sure you'll see plenty of examples. If you have some code to show that you want help on then post a new question.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! I understand how to recursively traverse a tree with ```Preorder(node->left) and Preorder(node->right)``` however that method assumes I have access to a node in as a function parameter. I will do some more digging, again thanks for helping out!

Comment: @motantan Yes it does. The way I would recommend it is to write a *helper function* that takes a node as a parameter (and the visit function pointer). The helper function is the recursive one, and the main function just calls the helper function with the tree root as the node parameter.

Answer (score 2):

This is a parameter of type pointer to function accepting `const Node *` and returns `void` and the name of the parameter is `visit`.

In other words if you have a function like `func()`, you can pass it to `BST::Preorder()`

```
void func(const Node * )
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void BST::Preorder(void(*visit)(const Node *))
```

- This is `Preorder` function of `BST` class.
- The parameter of that function is a function pointer.
- `*visit` means it's a function pointer that accept a `const Node *` as its own paremeter and return void.

So generally you would have to implement that `visit` function elsewhere. Then uses that `visit` function somewhere in `Preorder` function.